# Jersey path param injection

Tags: jersey

The current Jeresy doc (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html) shows this example.

```
@Path("{id:\\d+}")
public class InjectedResource {
    // Injection onto field
    @DefaultValue("q") @QueryParam("p")
    private String p;

    // Injection onto constructor parameter
    public InjectedResource(@PathParam("id") int id) { ... }

    // Injection onto resource method parameter
    @GET
    public String get(@Context UriInfo ui) { ... }

    // Injection onto sub-resource resource method parameter
    @Path("sub-id")
    @GET
    public String get(@PathParam("sub-id") String id) { ... }

    // Injection onto sub-resource locator method parameter
    @Path("sub-id")
    public SubResource getSubResource(@PathParam("sub-id") String id) { ... }

    // Injection using bean setter method
    @HeaderParam("X-header")
    public void setHeader(String header) { ... }
}
```

I don't understand how this particular injection is intended to work:

```
// Injection onto sub-resource resource method parameter
        @Path("sub-id")
        @GET
        public String get(@PathParam("sub-id") String id) { ... }
```

Where would the value for for sub-id come from? I've implemented this code and tried the following:

This results in the id param being null

```
curl localhost:9090/JerseySample/1234/sub-id
```

This results in a 404

```
curl localhost:9090/JerseySample/1234/sub-id/1234
```

Is it a typo and meant to look like this ?

```
  // Injection onto sub-resource resource method parameter
            @Path("{sub-id}")
            @GET
            public String get(@PathParam("sub-id") String id) { ... }
```

Comment: Looks like a typo.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yep, my alternative above works. I was wondering if I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code (@Path("sub-id")) - it looks like you are expecting a sub-id as part of your path - use below (here 1234 is ur sub-id)
@Path("/{sub-id}")
localhost:9090/JerseySample/1234

Comment: Before writing an answer, please take the time to carefully read and understand the question. If you have any doubts or questions about the details of the problem, consider leaving a comment to ask for clarification. This will help ensure that the answers provided are accurate and useful. @Ash.